# Executing command after doing ssh to a remote server

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to execute a script to `ssh` to a remote host and execute a `zcat` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in abc.net
do
    ssh $server "echo $svr"; zcat /tmp/abc.log.gz|egrep "15 10:0[0-9]"|cut -d'|' -f6|cut -d':' -f1|grep Pattern |sort|uniq -c
done
```

The result shows as follows. Removing the ssh messages:

```
Password: 
abc.net
zcat: /tmp/abc.log.gz: No such file or directory
```

The file `abc.log.gz` does exist under `/tmp` on the remote machine

Comment: the zcat part is not running through ssh! ssh is just executes the echo on remote machine and the rest is running on your local machine; put the entire commands which you want execute remotely in quotes after ssh command

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remotely execute a series of commands, the entire command series needs to be quoted:

```
#!/bin/bash

for server in abc.net; do
    echo "$server" 
    ssh "$server" 'zcat /tmp/abc.log.gz|egrep "15 10:0[0-9]"|cut -d\| -f6|cut -d: -f1|grep Pattern |sort|uniq -c'
done
```

Alternatively, you can slice and side all of the output locally rather than remotely:

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in host1.example.com host2.example.com; do
    ssh "$server" 'zcat /tmp/abc.log.gz'
done | egrep "15 10:0[0-9]" |cut -d'|' -f6 | cut -d: -f1 | grep Pattern | sort | uniq -c'
```